# how to modify error when row not found in zend doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3

So I have this exact error and it happens when there is an association and that row isn't found with the matching ID.

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615232/entity-of-type-appbundle-entity-user-for-ids-id155-was-not-found)

I have searched through but couldn't find any such solution to the problem. Is there any way to tell doctrine to ignore if row not found? Or if modifying error.

I could query to check but that isn't appropriate since we call via `$entity->getOtherEntity()`

Comment: I think this might be an issue of either: 1) someone manually f****d the data in the DB, or 2) floating records. In case of the first: slap someone 'till they understand. In case of the second: you might want to look into [Orphan Removal](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal). I say this because, theoretically, when properly setup, it shouldn't happen that a relation exists to a non-existant record. So, either manually or by faulty logic, the reference has dissappeared.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about. It happens when someone does bad to data manually. But, there should be a way to override the exception like adding a redirect instead.

Comment: Actually, this is why you write applications: fulfill the need to do stuff with data. The applications contain the necessary logic. If you want to the application to handle missing data, like what you've got because someone messes with the raw data, then you need to custom extend the ORM to be able to do this. Else, you'll have to loop the fetched data and for each object to check if it's good, like : `foreach($entity->getOtherEntity() as $child) { if ($child instanceof ChildEntity) { // do stuff }}`. Best solution: deny people direct access to your database. Or don't bother with an app...